# SQL query where 2 or more records exist in second table

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have 3 tables and want to select all of the records in table 1 where ALL the records in table 2 join table 3 and are checked.

I know there is a way with a sub-query, but do not know what it is.

A simple who is taking what classes question.

I am using sqlite3 as the database.

`Students` table t1 (id int, name text)

```
id      name
------- ---------
1       Smith
2       Jones
3       Wilson
--------------------------------------------------
```

`Classes` table t2 (class int, student int)

```
class   student
------- ---------
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
3       1
3       3
4       2
4       3
```

`Selected` table t3 (t3class int, t3checked boolean)

```
t3Class t3Checked
------- ---------
1       false
2       false
3       true
4       true
```

Who is taking the classes

```
Class   Name
-----   --------
1,2 = Smith, Jones
1,3 = Smith, Wilson
1,4 = Jones, Wilson
1,2,4   = Jones
1,2,3,4 =
```

Comment: I am not quite sure this is it.  I am only looking for the students that have taken the classes.  So, if table 3 had all false and class1&2 true, the answer would be Smith and Jones.

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I am not able to edit or remove it.

 I am not quite sure this is it.  

 I am looking for a query that would only return students that have taken ALL the classes that are marked true.

 So, 
 If the selected table only had 1 & 2 as true,
 Smith & Jones would be returned.

 if the Selected table had 1 & 3 as true,
 Smith & Wilson would be returned.

 if the selected table had 1 & 2 & 4 as true
 only Jones would be returned

 if the selected table had 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 as true
 no records would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work in SQLite, because it doesn't support `order by` in `group_concat()`.  But, you can try this:

```
select classes, group_concat(student)
from (select student, group_concat(class) as classes
      from classes c
      group by student
     ) sc
 group by classes;
```

In MySQL, the correct version would be:

```
select classes, group_concat(student order by student)
from (select student, group_concat(class order by class) as classes
      from classes c
      group by student
     ) sc
group by classes;
```

The ordering is needed to ensure that two students with the same classes have them in the proper order.

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for.
I am looking for a query that would only return students that have taken ALL the classes that are marked true. 
In the selected table 
if 1 & 2 are true, Smith & Jones would be returned.
if 1 & 3 are true, Smith & Wilson would be returned.
if 1 & 2 & 4 are true only Jones would be returned  
if 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 are true no records would be returned

Comment: @user2797484 . . . Your results include classes 1 and 2, even though they are not selected.  I am confused.

Comment: I am describing it incorrectly.  Basically, the "Selected" table is being updated by the end user.  When I say 1&2 above, I am indicating that they selected 1&2 and all other values are false.  So the different scenarios described above are created by changing the Selected table.  I am basically looking for a query that will find rows only if ALL the selected records are present.